# Django DB delete filtered Objects

Tags: python, django, database, backend

I'm trying to delete a user's all related messages. All messages sent by all users are located in a Message Model. So, to delete a specific user's messages only, I have to filter this Message.Model and sort it by user.

```
def clear(request):
    user_msg = request.user
    relative_message = Message.objects.filter(user=user_msg)
    Message.objects.filter(id=relative_message).delete()
```

My code is not working and gives me a Value Error:

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Comment: Does `Message.objects.filter(user=user_msg).delete()` solve your problem? It seems like the extra step you are doing with `relative_message` is unnecessary. Also `relative_message` is a QuerySet object. So you are passing `filter(id=relative_message)` a QuerySet instead of an integer.

Comment: It's not clear what the queries are intended to do. Why not just `Message.objects.filter(user=user_msg).delete()`? Think you need to post your Message object and clarify what is uset_msg.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code as below:

```
def clear(request):
    Message.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
```